# Can we set the save URL on sforce.one.createRecord

Tags: visualforce, community

I used sforce.one.createRecord in VF page for Lightning experience. Now I want that on the click of Save button, the record should be saved and popup should close (the parent window should not be redirected to any other page).
Currently, it is being redirected to the newly created record.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

No, this seems currently not possible, since it is not officially stated in the documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm

Per default it routes to the newly generated object, which is often NOT what we need. We can only hope, that Salesforce recognizes the severe necessity for us to get control on where the users end up after the insert. For many use cases I need to create child records and navigate to the parent. Not possible now :-(